# How to design GUI correctly, using Swing?

Tags: java, swing

I'm building a game in Java, and now I'm dealing with the GUI of the game.
This is the design I want to make.
[image]

My question is, is it a good idea to make each panel as a separate class that extends JPanel, and add each panel to the JFrame accordingly?

For example this is my menu panel

```
public class MenuPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

    private OptionsDialog optionsDialog;

    public SidePanel(JFrame mainFrame){

        Box box = Box.createVerticalBox();

        optionsDialog = new OptionsDialog(mainFrame, "Options", true);
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        Dimension size = getPreferredSize();
        size.width = 125;
        setPreferredSize(size);
        this.setBackground(new Color(140,100,70));

        JButton startGameButton = new JButton("Start Game");
        JButton scoreTableButton = new JButton("Score Table");
        JButton optionsButton = new JButton("Options");
        JButton rulesButton = new JButton("Rules");
        JButton exitButton = new JButton("Exit");

        startGameButton.addActionListener(this);
        scoreTableButton.addActionListener(this);
        optionsButton.addActionListener(this);
        rulesButton.addActionListener(this);
        exitButton.addActionListener(this);

        box.add(startGameButton);
        box.add(scoreTableButton);
        box.add(optionsButton);
        box.add(rulesButton);
        box.add(exitButton);
        add(box);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            //optionsDialog.setVisible(true);
    }    
}
```

Another thing, how can I notify each panel that a change has appeared on a different panel? For example the user changed the game options and started the game, I need to notify the game panel to load it components according to the new options. Should I use the Observer design pattern for this type of communication?

Comment: >"is it a good idea to make each panel as a separate class that extends JPanel" - the answer to this is largely opinion-based, but there are certain objective benefits to this approach, namely a cleaner code base that's easier to maintain.

Comment: Thanks @Strikegently, my other idea was just to dump everything GUI related into the main JFrame class but it will result in a dirty and massive code that would be hard to maintain. Is there any other approach that you can recommend?

Comment: At any point you want to separate the responsibilities of each section as much as possible. While they might represent a small part of a larger model, you want each element to focus on as small a part as possible. This allows you to focus on providing the functionality required to manage those parts of the model in the simplest form. The MVC paradigm would argue in favour of separating each panel into it's own class, it would also provide the means for allowing communication between the view and the model as a whole

Comment: Another question you want to ask is, how easy would it be to replace any part of the UI with a different implementation?  If you find yourself struggling with having to tear the UI apart each time, then you're probably using the wrong design. If how ever, they are decouple in such away that you can perform a drop in replacement, you're probably moving in the right direction

Comment: Also, if you find that another part of your code is taking on a lot of responsibility for actions/management of one or more the UI components, it's probably the wrong approach.  Isolate the various levels of responsibility. Updating the data is the responsibility of the model, getting input from the user is the responsibility of the UI, neither should be directly influencing the other or trying to perform their duties, this is where the controller comes in